# Want to get difference between two dates in js?

Tags: javascript, date

I tried so many solution on stack overflow itself, but not get the difference in js.

I was using

```
var days = ('13-10-2018'- '13-09-2018') / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)]
```

Comment: Why tagging with c# when you're looking for a js solution?

Comment: *Difference between two dates in `js`* Then why it is tagged to `c#` and `Oracle`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are 2 issues here.

First, you need to use your date strings to construct a proper JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, which only supports IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601, as you can see in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters). Therefore, you can't use `DD-MM-YYYY`, but you could use `MM-DD-YYYY`

Another way to construct a `Date` object is to use this syntax:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

So, to calculate the difference between 2 dates in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, you first need to parse that and create two `Date` objects. Then, you call [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) in both of them and calculate the absolute difference in milliseconds. Lastly, you convert that to days dividing by `3600000 * 24` and rounding (if you don't want decimal days):

```js
function getDateFromDDMMYYYY(dateString) {
  const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/');
    
  return new Date(
    parseInt(year),
    parseInt(month) - 1,
    parseInt(day)
  );
}

const diff = Math.abs(getDateFromDDMMYYYY('13/10/2018').getTime() - getDateFromDDMMYYYY('13/09/2018').getTime());
const days = Math.round(diff / (3600000 * 24)); 

console.log(`${ days } ${ days === 1 ? 'day' : 'days' }`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to subtract dates ('13-10-2018'- '13-09-2018') is wrong. This will give an error NaN (Not a number) because '13-10-2018' for instance is a string and can't be automatically converted to a Date object. if you ask '100' - '20' this will give you 80 as javascript automatically parses a string that can be converted to integers or floats when arithmetic operators are applied but in your case, it's '13-10-2018' that can't be parsed either as an integer or float because parsing it won't give any number.

If the date is in **string** format then you can parse it in following way and then perform some operation, Since your date is in **DD-MM-YYYY** I suggest you change it either in **MM-DD-YYYY** or in **YYYY-MM-DD**, for more info about Date you can look up to the this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
let timeDifference = Math.abs(new Date('10-13-2018') - new Date('09-13-2018'));
console.log(Math.ceil( timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
```

new Date('10-13-2018') - new Date('09-13-2018') will give you 2592000000 milliseconds, since time is represented as [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). you can check unix time of any date by doing following.

```
console.log(new Date().getTime('10-13-2018'));
```

now the calculations behind the scene is 2592000000 / 1000*60*60*24 (that is total milliseconds in one day) = 30 days